# How can I use month name as contextual filter?

Tags: views, 8

I have a contextual filter to filter by month:

Date in the form of MM (01 - 12).

However, I want to filter by month name (january, february, march, etc.) to get nicer URL and breadcrumb.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Just FYI Calendar module comes with month name contextuals. I haven't tried it in D8 but maybe you can check it out and see if it fits.

Comment: Thanks for this tips, I tested, but looks like it is not there in D8 yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically alter the contextual filter value of "january" to "01 - 12" in [hook_views_pre_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/8.2.x)

```
/*
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view()
 */
function mymodule_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
  // Modify contextual filters for my_special_view.
  if ($view->id() == 'my_special_view') {
    // insert here some php magic to format "January" to "01".
    $og_arg = t('@og_arg', ['@og_arg' => $args[0]], ['langcode' => 'en']);
    $date = date_parse($og_arg);
    // assign formatted value.
    $args[0] = $date['month'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I needed to check if arg is set at all to make the view work with empty arg. Also the month need to be in formate 01-12. I also wanted to make numeric month values work. In the end I used like this:
`/*
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view()
 */
function mymodule_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
  if (($view->id() == 'my_special_view') && isset($args[0]) && !is_numeric($args[0])){
    $og_arg = $args[0];
    $date = date_parse($og_arg);
    $args[0] = sprintf('%02d', $date['month']);
  }
}`

Comment: However I'm not able to make it work for multilingual sites, where month names should be translated to other languages

Comment: You can translate it with the [t()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/8.4.x). `$og_arg = t('@og_arg', ['@og_arg' => $args[0]], ['langcode' => 'en']);`

Comment: This is what I also tried, but t() translate from english to other languages, but in this case we need to translate month name from other languages to English (to be able to parse them as dates). I tested your suggestion and it adds the translated month names as new source strings to be translated, so it is not working :/ but thanks!

Comment: The code I gave ya is suppose to tranlate from other language to english. Is there a translation set for the months? If you `print t('january')` does it translate when u switch site to other language?

Comment: I'm in D8 and yes the strings are translated, but this code add translated strings as new source strings

Comment: Are you able to enter a translation for those "new source" strings?

Comment: Sorry I think those source strings were there from before. It seems like t() is not being validated at all inside the hook!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to make it work for multilingual websites. This is how I solved it in the end:

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup;

/*
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view()
 */
function mymodule_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
  if (($view->id() == 'my_special_view') && isset($args[0]) && !is_numeric($args[0])){
    $og_arg = $args[0];
    switch($og_arg){
      case strtolower(new TranslatableMarkup('January', [], ['context' => 'Long month name'])):
        $args[0] = '01';
        break;
      case strtolower(new TranslatableMarkup('February', [], ['context' => 'Long month name'])):
        $args[0] = '02';
        break;
      case strtolower(new TranslatableMarkup('March', [], ['context' => 'Long month name'])):
        $args[0] = '03';
        break;
      case strtolower(new TranslatableMarkup('April', [], ['context' => 'Long month name'])):
        $args[0] = '04';
        break;
      case strtolower(new TranslatableMarkup('May', [], ['context' => 'Long month name'])):
        $args[0] = '05';
        break;
      case strtolower(new TranslatableMarkup('June', [], ['context' => 'Long month name'])):
        $args[0] = '06';
        break;
      case strtolower(new TranslatableMarkup('July', [], ['context' => 'Long month name'])):
        $args[0] = '07';
        break;
      case strtolower(new TranslatableMarkup('August', [], ['context' => 'Long month name'])):
        $args[0] = '08';
        break;
      case strtolower(new TranslatableMarkup('September', [], ['context' => 'Long month name'])):
        $args[0] = '09';
        break;
      case strtolower(new TranslatableMarkup('October', [], ['context' => 'Long month name'])):
        $args[0] = '10';
        break;
      case strtolower(new TranslatableMarkup('November', [], ['context' => 'Long month name'])):
        $args[0] = '11';
        break;
      case strtolower(new TranslatableMarkup('December', [], ['context' => 'Long month name'])):
        $args[0] = '12';
        break;
    }
  }
```